# Etymology of Latin infinitive verb endings

Tags: etymology, historical-linguistics, grammar, latin

I was wondering, what the etymology of Latin infinitive verb endings *-are*, *-ere* and *-ire* was. I assume they are Indo-European, but I haven't found any information about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Latin infinitive verb endings -are, -ere and -ire can be analyzed as the thematic vowels of the verbs -a-, -e- and -i- plus -re < *-s-e(y), with rhotacism r < s.
The same morpheme *-s- exists in Greek -ein < *e-s-en with intervocalic loss of s.
You should find more detailed information in manuals.

Comment: Which manuals? Can you give a reference or link?