# Where did the word ending ar er ir in Spanish come fom?

Tags: etymology, spanish

When I was learning Spanish, I came across the fact that Spanish verbs have three classes: AR, ER, and IR. I notice that more of them have the AR verb ending.

The verb endings are the same in Latin, but is there a root from Proto-Indo-European that determines these verb endings? If there is, it is probably not 100% across the board because some ER/ERE verbs in Latin got turned into IR verbs. If there isn't an obvious one, then is there a tendency for AR verbs to have one type of trait(s) and the other types to have another trait or group of traits?

What I mean by "where do they come from" is in part about if there are words that are roots.

Comment: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7601/where-did-the-latin-language-get-its-infinitive-verb-endings-from

Comment: That works, thanks.

Comment: Related: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17607/9385

Comment: See also [Etymology of Latin infinitive verb endings](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/30397/443)

Answer (score 3):

In Latin, the present infinitive was marked with a suffix *-(e)re* attached to the verb stem. This ended up creating four fairly-regular categories: stems ending in *-ā*, with infinitives in *-āre*; stems ending in *-ē*, with infinitives in *-ēre*; stems ending in *-ī*, with infinitives in *-īre*; and stems ending in anything else, with infinitives in *-ere*. Eventually, in Vulgar Latin/Proto-Romance, this fourth "catch-all" group got split up and its verbs redistributed among the others, giving the familiar Spanish categories of *-ar*, *-er*, *-ir*.

So, the real question is, where did these four different "flavors" of stems come from?

Well, in Proto-Indo-European, there were quite a lot of different ways to turn a basic root into a verb stem. Most of these involved suffixes of some sort, so these suffixes determined the ending of the stem that was passed down to Latin:

- "Root verbs" (no suffix) generally ended in consonants, so they went into the *-ere* class
- Verbs suffixed with **-ye* ended up in the *-ere* or *-īre* classes
- Verbs suffixed with **-eh₁* ended up in the *-ēre* class
- Verbs suffixed with **-eh₂* ended up in the *-āre* class
- Verbs suffixed with anything else went into the *-ere* class

So for most verbs, which class they ended up in, depended on which method was used to turn the root into a verb in Proto-Indo-European. Sometimes this affected the meaning, but sometimes it didn't, and it was just an accident of fate that the verb formed with **-ye* caught on and the one formed with **-eh₁* didn't.